# date-fns - countdown from date including weeks

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I am building a countdown clock, and I am using date-fns. I need to be able to countdown from a date including the number of weeks. The documentation [here](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/formatDuration) looks like formatDuration returns the number of weeks but doesn't seem to and wonder if I need to use something else?

I'm aware of the differenceInWeeks function they provide, but not sure how suitable that would be in my case.

Thanks in advance.

```js
import { intervalToDuration, formatDuration } from 'date-fns';

const units = ['years', 'months', 'weeks', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'];
  let duration = intervalToDuration({
    start: new Date(2022, 6, 2, 0, 0, 15),
    end: new Date(),
  });

  formatDuration(duration, {
    format: units,
    delimiter: ', ',
  });

// Returns years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds but not weeks
```

Comment: Weeks seem to only be supported if they are explicitly included in the duration, e.g. `formatDuration({ years: 2, months: 9, weeks: 3 })` (see [date-fns *formatDuration* documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/formatDuration)). You can run code at [npm.runkit.com/date-fns](https://npm.runkit.com/date-fns) for play.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a duration, date-fns doesn't add weeks by default and if they aren't in the duration, the formatter won't show them.

You can manually add weeks using a function based on the value for *days*, e.g.

```
function addWeeks(duration) {
  if (!duration.weeks) {
    duration.weeks = duration.days / 7 | 0;
    duration.days = duration.days - duration.weeks*7;
  }
}
```

You may want to test if *duration.days* exists before using it. Then do something like:

```
let duration = intervalToDuration({
  start: new Date(2022, 6, 2, 0, 0, 15),
  end: new Date()
});

// Add weeks if missing
addWeeks(duration);

let formattedDuration = formatDuration(duration, {
  format: units,
  delimiter: ', '
});

// "1 year, 9 months, 1 week, 1 day, 10 hours, 39 minutes, 27 seconds"
console.log(formattedDuration);
```